# how to generate new fields in logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I need to generate the new fields (**loglevel**) using logstash,finally displaying in kibana.

[image: log file format of Log4jNet log file]

1. How to extract this log and make the pattern using grok filter for this log.
2. How to create the field of **loglevel** using logstash configuration.

Comment: The best way to start making grok patterns is with the grok debugger: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.ben-morris.com/using-logstash-elasticsearch-and-log4net-for-centralized-logging-in-windows/) page helpful when I was setting up my log4net filter.  Based on what your logs look like, you'll end up with something like this (copied from that page):

```
filter {
  if [type] == "log4net" {
    grok {
      match => [ "message", "(?m)%{LOGLEVEL:level} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:sourceTimestamp} %{DATA:logger} \[%{NUMBER:threadId}\]  \[%{IPORHOST:tempHost}\] %{GREEDYDATA:tempMessage}" ]
    }
    mutate {
        replace => [ "message" , "%{tempMessage}" ]
        replace => [ "host" , "%{tempHost}" ]
        remove_field => [ "tempMessage" ]
        remove_field => [ "tempHost" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Right @Samuel, but my logs are different when come to the GREEDYDATA, misssing some data in the log message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Now i got an answer. Please find the below configuration for creating new fields and filter some fields.

```
filter {
    multiline{
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
            what => "previous"
            negate=> true
        } 
    # Delete trailing whitespaces
      mutate {
        strip => "message"
      }    
    # Delete \n from messages
    mutate {
        gsub => ['message', "\n", " "]
    }  
    # Delete \r from messages
    mutate {
        gsub => ['message', "\r", " "]
    }

    grok { 
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{NUMBER:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{JAVACLASS:class} - %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" } 
        }   
    if "Exception" in [msg] {
     mutate {
      add_field => { "msg_error" => "%{msg}" }
      }
    }
  }
```